# How to convert TB into byte in python? Converted value in bytes should not be in exponential

Tags: python

Example:
5 TB -> 5.498e + 12 Bytes

Here the answer should not be in exponential.

Comment: TB = `10^12`, [TiB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tebibyte) = `2^40` = `1024^4`

Comment: Try avoiding to write the whole question in the Topic and then giving just an example in the post.

Comment: @adil http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207654/question-body-containing-the-question-as-well

Comment: @Bleeding Fingers thanks for the tag....but I meant `Coverting TB to byte` in Title and rest as main content...(short title good description)...
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145019/what-should-i-write-in-the-question-body-if-the-title-already-explains-everythin

Answer (score 0):

You would use a sum that looks something like this.

```
tb = 5
gb =((tb) * (1024))
mb =(gb * (1024))
kb =(mb * (1024))
byte =(kb * (1024))
print (byte)
```

Comment: You're confusing [TB (terabyte)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terabyte) with [TiB (tebibyte)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tebibyte).

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon whether you mean [Terabyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terabyte) (10^12) or [Tebibyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tebibyte) (2^40):

```
>>> print 5*10**12
5000000000000
>>> print 5*2**40
5497558138880
>>>
```